# Modify EventType GUI.TextFields respond to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have build a `scrollview` that contains Buttons, `TextFields` and Toggles.

When I scroll the view holding a TextField, then it gets focused as soon as I put my finger on the screen (`EventType = MouseDown`) which is a terrible UX since you don't want that to happen when you're scrolling down/up.

**Is there anyway to focus `TextFields` only when the `MouseUp` event is triggered and not before?**

Comment: What GUI framework are you using? Your own? Unity's default? NGUI? Something else?

Comment: It's Unity's default (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what your problem is, because I can use the scroll view without a nearby text field getting the focus. However, you can manipulate the event right before the text field. With the following code the text field will get the focus on `MouseUp`, no matter where you started the `MouseDown`...

```
void OnGUI()
{
    var typeBackup = Event.current.type;

    switch (Event.current.type)
    {
        case EventType.MouseDown:
            Debug.Log(Event.current);
            Event.current.type = EventType.Ignore;
            break;
        case EventType.MouseUp:
            Debug.Log(Event.current);
            Event.current.type = EventType.MouseDown;
            break;
    }

    GUILayout.TextField("I will not steal focus on MouseDown");

    if (Event.current.type != EventType.Used)
        Event.current.type = typeBackup;

}
```

Depending on the rest of your `OnGUI()` method, you may or may not need to save the original event type and restore it after the text field. If nothing cares for a `MouseDown` event after the text field, it should be safe to omit that part.

You could fine tune the behavior by matching the positions of the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events, so that the text field would only get focus if both events were above it.